# Geometry Nodes: Is it possible to change light power?

Tags: geometry-nodes, lighting, drivers, properties, instances

Is it possible to drive the power of an instanced light through geometry nodes?

Use Case:

In the scene there are a couple of instance lights driven by geometry nodes in a point cloud. The lights are dimmed with increasing distance to a specified object and removed from the selection when illumination reaches zero to manage large point clouds. At the moment only the size is driven by the distance to the object, which does not affect emission strength. The lights therefore just suddenly appear and disappear and do not dim. As a solution the strength setting of the individual instances could be decreased before removing a light from the selection.

Is it possible to access this value for single instances of a light?

Comment: If not, you could check *use nodes* on the light itself and do a distance comparison from the desired object.

Comment: I can´t manage to get geometry nodes working on the light as it is not a "mesh object". I can get the position of the light into the shader nodes, but there it is not possible to get the position of the moving object. Also I wonder if this would work on the instances, as I think the position obtained could be just the one of the original light object.